# Create Widget using ASP.Net. html and jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, widget

i have created an jQuery based voice recorder application in ASP.Net. This application accepts voice and asp.net page saves it on a web-server's folder. Now, i have to develop it like a widget so that i can use this on different application using java script. I tried to use IFrame, but i am looking for more better way.

Comment: This is not a good way to ask IMO. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems, not for providing solutions about some frameworks or etc..

Comment: its related to issue that i am facing while developing widget, i am not able to find a way to call widget on client using java script.

Comment: What exactly has been saved to the web server's folder? Is it a mp3/wav file?

Comment: its .wav file, that is saved on web server

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit on the technical background which enables you to perform voice recording. Also please shed light on how that iframe was used?